# Change text/font case ANYWHERE including chrome input fields

Tags: mac, copy-paste, case

Trying to find a solution to be able to easily change text case inside of a chrome input field. I know word editors have features like right click > transformations > UPPERCASE, lowercase, Title Case.

I've been looking everywhere for a solution to be able to do this DIRECTLY INSIDE OF A FIELD.

Example situation. I have to copy data from a restaurant menu into a website database. I have a PDF provided to me. Everything is in caps or its mixed or the editing program makes it look all caps, but when copied and pasted it's actually lowercase.

When I pasted it into a text field on the website admin. I want to be able to right click, and choose to change the case right there. No other work arounds.

Anyone know of a chrome extension or mac mods that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is a context menu (i.e. right-click) service that will allow you to toggle text case, yes?

If so, what I use for that purpose is a bit of freeware from DEVONTechnologies called WordService. They describe it, thusly:

> **WordService**
>
> WordService provides a large number of commands for working with selected text. Extend your favorite word processor, email app, or web browser e.g. with functions for reformating text paragraphs, cleaning up tabs, quotes, or line endings. Remove unwanted text parts, sort lines or paragraphs, change case, and do much, much more with text.

The services install to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services -> Text and you can toggle the ones you want/don't want on/off and set key command shortcuts for them.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In the right-click menu, the services will appear similarly to the below (minus my additional services):

[image]

And will easily let you transform text field input:

[image]
[image]

You can download WordService, either, directly from [DEVONTechnologies' site](https://www.devontechnologies.com/download/) or from [the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wordservice/id899972312?mt=12) and it is also available via the [homebrew](https://brew.sh) command: `brew cask install wordservice`.